# Changing those elements of a matrix to zero which are not in a column of another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 100x100 matrix `A` (containing values ​​from 0 to 150) and a 35x4 matrix `B`. In matrix `A`, I want to keep only those values ​​that are present in column 3 of `B` i.e. `B(:,3)` and change all other values in `A` to zero. So the size of `A` will remain unchanged. Is this achievable?

I started to make a code beginning with a loop traversing the matrix `A`, another one going through column 3 of `B` and an `if`-statement to signify the equality condition that I want but how to correctly define the finality of the loop?

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
    for j=1:size(B,3)
        if ismember (A(i,i),B(j,3))
            A(B(j,3))=A; % it's false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You want to keep only those values of `A` that correspond to column 3 of `B`. Fine. But what do you mean by **keeping the size of `A` unchanged**? If you want to keep a few values then the size will obviously change

Comment: Yes I want my matrix A to remain a matrix [100x100]. Another way to see things is that the values ​​of A different from those in column 3 of B would be zeroed. Is this achievable?

Comment: I can a propose a non-loopy solution if you're interested

Comment: Yes why not it can be interesting :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without loops using [**`ismember`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) as follows:

```
 A=A.*ismember(A,B(:,3))
```